# IIS Symfony twig Template is not defined

Tags: symfony, iis, twig

I have a problem on a IIS server. Everything works on my local MAMP setup and my online LAMP setup. By my client wants to run the Symfony application on his own IIS server in the office.

I'm using Symfony forms to display a form. So I have a file with form_start() and form_end() because I have to control every field.

The render engine of the CMS ([Fork CMS](https://github.com/forkcms/forkcms)) refers to a file FormLayout.html.twig. And that file extends from fomr_div_layout.html.twig. But for some reason, IIS gives me this error:

```
Template "C:\inetpub\sites\...\FormLayout.html.twig" is not defined in Profiles\Layout\Templates\Index.html.twig at line 12.
```

The path exists and MAMP and LAMP does not have any problems with it. The path is also defined in the Twig_Loader_Chain.

So any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you please show what Line 12 of the file: `Profiles\Layout\Templates\Index.html.twig` contains?

Comment: You need to use the relative path starting from the template folder defined in the Twig configuration, don't use absolute paths

Comment: @AlvinBunk That's form_start()

Comment: @DarkBee I changed that, now I'm getting the error 

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("No block "form_start" found while rendering the form.") in Profiles\Layout\Templates\Index.html.twig at line 12.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the custom Twig template engine. But no idea why it only gives issues in IIS.

Comment: You should post your code, otherwise it could be hard for us to help you!